# Show image zoom window for picture using jquery

Tags: jquery, image, svg, zooming, effect

I have SVG images on a page. When you hover over the SVG, I want to see a zoom up of the area I'm hovering over. I don't want the zoom effect window to be placed relative to my cursor. I have a box in my navigation which I want the zoomed image to be placed in. I was looking into a bunch of Zoom plugins, but I could not find any that would allow me to place the zoom in a custom place on my page.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.